# Text wrapping around an image (or any element)

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Is there a way with CSS to wrap text on *both* sides of an element (an image for example).  I am trying to have an image positioned in the middle of a paragraph and would like text to flow over it. Please see the image for an example.
[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/14mvp69.jpg]

Positioning an element typically takes it out of the document flow; so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, no. Not without working with multiple text-columns.

I just threw together one possible solution. You can access it at http://www.sampsonresume.com/labs/img-in-middle/

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I have seen similar to this would be the A List Apart article: [Cross-Column Pull-Out Part Two: Custom Silhouettes](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn2). You still need multiple text columns, and even ALA lists it as "experimental". It may be worth checking out, though.

[Example here](http://www.alistapart.com/d/crosscolumn2/example0.html).

Comment: Thanks for that Zack; it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not without some very tricky/tedious text parsing.  But anyone trying to read that text would hate you if you made them jump back and forth across an image twice per line, so that's probably a good thing.